# How to get element based on coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Suppose i have coordinates like top: 995, left: 216. Now i want to get the element in the DOM which is in this position (or an element of a particular class which is closest to this element) . Something like:

```
var element = coordinates().closest('this class');
```

How to achieve this is javascript (jquery or angularjs solution would also work).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use [**`Document.elementFromPoint()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

*The `elementFromPoint()` method of the Document interface returns the topmost `element` at the specified `coordinates`.*

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```